# input channels does not match filter's input channels (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I would like to use `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` to build a deconvolution layer for a GAN network.

I would like to create a function `deconv_layer`. It generates a new layer, which outputs `filter_num` filters with `expand_size` times the resolution of the input.

My code is:

```
def deconv_layer(x, filter_num, kernel_size=5, expand_size=2):

    x_shape = x.get_shape().as_list()

    with tf.name_scope('deconv_'+str(filter_num)):

        size_in = x_shape[-1]
        size_out = filter_num

        w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([kernel_size, kernel_size, size_in, size_out], mean=0.0, stddev=0.125), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([size_out], mean=0.0, stddev=0.125), name="B")

        conv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, w, output_shape=[-1, x_shape[-3]*expand_size, x_shape[-2]*expand_size, filter_num], strides=[1,expand_size,expand_size,1], padding="SAME")
        act = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b))

        tf.summary.histogram('weights', w)
        tf.summary.histogram('biases', b)
        tf.summary.histogram('activations', act)

    return act
```

The error message:

```
ValueError: input channels does not match filter's input channels
At conv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(...)
```

I am not sure if I use `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` properly. I tried to create it based on a convolutional layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter dimension is wrong. According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose):

> filter: A 4-D Tensor with the same type as value and shape [height,
>   width, output_channels, in_channels]. filter's in_channels dimension
>   must match that of value (input).

You need to change your `w` size to :

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([kernel_size, kernel_size, size_out, size_in], mean=0.0, stddev=0.125), name="W")
```